# Back navigation impossible when iframe with dynamic src in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-router-dom

I am having a hard time understanding a back navigation issue that occurs in our project.

We are working in a React environment (v17), with react-router-dom (v6) and we render an iframe on a third party service (therefore the iframe src is on a different domain) on our page (the issue happens as well in NextJS).

The page that renders the iframe gets the url from the navigation state (using `useLocation()` from react-router-dom) and puts that in the iframe src.

When we press the browser back button (or use `history.back()`, or `history.go(-1)` in the browser console, or `navigate(-1)` from the `useNavigate` hook), nothing happens but the iframe content being reloaded.

No `popstate` event is being dispatched, and the browser history does not change.

If I hardcode the iframe URL (so no reading the value from some place else), everything works as expected. Also, if I refresh the page, things work fine as well if I press the back button twice (¯\*(ツ)*/¯)

I've found this [interesting article](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/react-iframes-back-navigation-bug/) regarding back navigation with React an iframes.
I tried adding a key to the iframe (like `Date.now()`) but nothing changes.

Here are some sketch components to put things together.

Page 1

```js
const Page1 = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  // in our case we are using a GraphQL mutation. 
  // this is just for demonstration purposes
  return <button onClick={() => {
    fetchIFrameURLOnTheServer()
      .then(url => navigate('/page2', { state: { url } }))
  }}>
    go to iframe page
  </button>
}
```

Page 2

```js
const Page2 = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { url } = location.state;
  return <iframe src={url} key={Date.now()} />;
}
```

Router declaration

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route element={<Layout />}> // <-- renders the <Outlet />
      <Route path='path1' element={Page1}/>
      <Route path='path2' element={Page2}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I would like to understand what happen and I am seeking some help :P
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as you, I tried fixing it with the solution of the article you provided, and it worked for me!

I first tryed with the Date.now() function and a random function to generate the key for the iFrame, but neither of this worked.

What worked for me was using a content ID for the key as suggested in [the article](https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/react-iframes-back-navigation-bug/), so in summary, my guess is you should try using something different to Date.now() to generate the key of the iframe component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).